# Auto using typescript compiler in Netbeans

Tags: node.js, typescript, netbeans

I would like to use Netbeans for NodeJS development with Typescript, so when I run a `.ts` file from Netbeans, it should automatically compile with typescript compiler and then should run the compiled `.js` file with nodeJS, but I cannot make it work.

I don't have a TypeScript context menu as lot of webpages says, where I should check the 'compile on save' option.

I'm using Netbeans 8.2 on Windows 10, NetBeans TypeScript Editor plugin (3.0.1) is installed in Netbeans, nodeJS 8.12.0 is installed, typescript also installed.

Everything seems to work manually (I can call `tsc` on `.ts` file, which compiles then I can call `node` on the compiled `.js` file which runs the code; netbeans plugin also works: it gives me proper warning in `.ts` files), I just would like to automate the typescript compilation process.

Comment: Hello, I also have the same problem, I do not find in the properties of the project the Typescript framework.
Did you solve the problem in any way?

Answer (score 0):

This will not work at the moment in the typescript plugin (v3.0.1) for Netbeans created by @Everlaw

Only *.ts and tsconfig.json files are indexed for the compileOnSave option
I've created an issue at github:
https://github.com/Everlaw/nbts/issues/149

It might get solved in a future version. Otherwise only option is change the java code and compile yourself.